# How do I create a mouseover animation using Snap SVG?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I am creating a hover map animation using `Snap.svg`, but I seem to be having problems with the animation portion.  The map was created in `Illustrator` and exported as an `SVG` file and is linked to an `HTML` page.

Once I add the code below, everything disappears.

```
veryCold.mouseover(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: "#ff0000"
    }, 600);
}).mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: "#bada55"
    }, 200);
```

I am new to Stack Overflow, so please let me know if you need any additional information.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Snap.svg</title>
        <style>
        body {
            background: #333;   
            }
        </style>
        <script src="Snap.svg-0.4.1/dist/snap.svg.js"></script>
        <script src="Snap.svg-0.4.1/dist/snap-min.svg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="0" height="0">

        </svg>
        <script>
            var s = Snap(1080, 700);

            Snap.load("BuildingAmerica_ClimateMap_Vector-CJ-20150129-Buttons.svg", function(f) {
                var g = f.selectAll("g"),
                    wra = f.selectAll("path[class='st0']").attr({display: "none",}),
                    wrb = f.selectAll("path[class='st1']").attr({display: "inline", fill: "#FFFFFF"}),
                    wrc = f.selectAll("path[class='st2']").attr({"opacity": 0.75}),
                    wrd = f.selectAll("path[class='st3']").attr({fill: "#63B1C0"}),
                    wre = f.selectAll("path[class='st4']").attr({"opacity": 0, fill: "#63B1C0"}),
                    wrf = f.selectAll("path[class='st5']").attr({fill: "#C97F4C"}),
                    wrg = f.selectAll("path[class='st6']").attr({fill: "#B25415"}),
                    wrh = f.selectAll("path[class='st7']").attr({fill: "#C87D4B"}),
                    wri = f.selectAll("path[class='st8']").attr({"opacity": 0, fill: "#C97F4C"}),
                    wrj = f.selectAll("path[class='st9']").attr({fill: "#8CB533"}),
                    wrk = f.selectAll("path[class='st10']").attr({"opacity": 0, fill: "#8CB533"}),
                    wrl = f.selectAll("path[class='st11']").attr({fill: "#EEA135"}),
                    wrm = f.selectAll("path[class='st12']").attr({"opacity": 0, fill: "#EEA135"}),
                    wrn = f.selectAll("path[class='st13']").attr({fill: "#6D7CBC"}),
                    wro = f.selectAll("path[class='st14']").attr({fill: "#323E96"}),
                    wrp = f.selectAll("path[class='st15']").attr({fill: "#333B97"}),
                    wrq = f.selectAll("path[class='st16']").attr({"opacity": 0, fill:"#6D7CBC"}),
                    wrr = f.selectAll("path[class='st17']").attr({fill: "none", stroke: "#FFFFFF", strokeWidth: 0.2709}),
                    wrs = f.selectAll("path[class='st18']").attr({fill: "none", stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.4});

                s.append(g);
                s.append(wrb);
                s.append(wra);
                s.append(wrc);

                var veryCold = s.group(wrn, wro, wrp, wrq);
                veryCold.mouseover(function() {
                    this.animate({
                        fill: "#ff0000"
                        }, 600);
                    }).mouseout(function() {
                    this.animate({
                        fill: "#bada55"
                        }, 200);

                var mixedHumid = s.group(wrj, wrk);
                var hotHumid = s.group(wrl, wrm);
                var hotDry = s.group(wrf, wrg, wrh, wri);
                var marine = s.group(wrd, wre);

                s.append(wrr);
                s.append(wrs);
            });
        </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
veryCold.mouseover(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: "#ff0000"
    }, 600);
}).mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: "#bada55"
    }, 200);
}); // <--- It looks like you're missing this line
```

From what you've shared it looks like your code isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, 

I was definitely missing those closing elements, but this did not seem to get the animation to work.  I added the drag function .drag(); and it seemed to work.  Am I writing the animate function incorrectly?

I have 4 variables that I created that have different colors (wrn, wro, wrp, wrq).  I then grouped those 4 variables (into a group named veryCold) and am trying to get them all to change to the same color when the group (veryCold) is hovered.

I hope this makes sense.  I really appreciate your help.  Thank you.